# Proxy service with fixed IP

Tags: google-app-engine

Can anybody suggest a proxy IP service with a fixed IP address?

Google App Engine does not support fixed IP addresses. To verify certain transactions, I have to query my payment provider with a fixed IP. I have to configure a fixed IP.

Answer (score 0):

I use gAppProxy on appengine as proxy server, but appengine outgoing IP changed 3 times in 10 minutes, so that some website will shut my logined session